# How can I efficiently insert items in a table widget with PySide?

Tags: python, pyside

In my PySide application I have a button that when pressed the application connects to a database, retrieves the relevant data and inserts them in a table widget.

I use the following function for inserting items in the table widget, with alternating row colors:

```
def insert_data_to_table_widget(self, data, cols, table_widget):
    """ Insert items to table widget"""
    data = data[cols]
    for row_n, row in data.iterrows():
        table_widget.insertRow(row_n)
        status = row["Status"]
        for col_n, row_item in enumerate(row.iteritems()):
            item_value = row_item[1]
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", str(item_value),
                                                      None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
            item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
            font.setPointSize(12)
            font.setBold(False)
            font.setWeight(50)
            item.setFont(font)

            # Background color based on result
            background_colors = {"New": (255, 255, 255),
                                 "Won": (0, 170, 0),
                                 "Lost": (170, 0, 0)}
            if col_n == 0:
                try:
                    background_color = background_colors[status]
                except Exception as e:
                    # print "status not in dictionary":, e
                    background_color = (0, 0, 0)

                background_brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(*background_color))
                background_brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
                item.setBackground(background_brush)

            # Change foreground color
            if row_n % 2 != 0:  # Odd rows
                foreground_brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
            else:  # Even rows
                foreground_brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))

            if col_n == 0:  # First column with number
                if status == "New":
                    foreground_brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
                else:
                    foreground_brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))

            foreground_brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
            item.setForeground(foreground_brush)    

            table_widget.setItem(row_n, col_n, item)

    table_widget.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.resize_table_widget_columns(table_widget)
```

My data consist of 9000 rows with 20 columns at the moment.

It takes a few seconds to fill the table widget with all the data.
I intend to use a separate thread for this, in the future.

Is there a better way to fill a table widget than what I use ?

Comment: I recommend using a [Model/View approach](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html). That is, implement your own model derived from `QAbtractTableModel` and use a `QTableView` in your GUI. For a further performance improvement you can consider to retrieve your data in chucks with `fetchMore` (see, [this section](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#performance-optimization-for-large-amounts-of-data))

Comment: I have suspected that I would have to use a QTableView at some point. Will the performance be improved compared to a tablewidget ?

Comment: Yes, even without the `fetchMore` trick I expect an improvement.

Comment: Qstandarditemmodel is almost as easy to use as a qtablewidget.